# How do I delete item using ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the best way to delete an item in MVC? I have a list of items. Each row will contain a "Delete" link. I want the Delete link to prompt for confirmation, then delete the item from the datastore and refresh the page with the new data.

Here is my view code:

```
            <%: Ajax.ActionLink(
                "Delete"
                ,"Delete"
                , new { id=item.FooId}
                , new AjaxOptions()
                { 
                    Confirm="Are you sure that you want to delete this item?"
                    , HttpMethod = "post"} ) %>
```

And here is my controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var success = FooService.Deletefoo(id);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The record is being deleted, however the page is not refreshing. The only thing that I can think of is that RedirectToAction only works for different pages, not the same page.

How do I get the page to refresh?

Comment: Side note: Please don't use exceptions to control logic flow.  It's bad practice for a number of reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're page is not refreshing because the AJAX call is not going to honor a 302 - the RedirectToAction() is used when the entire browser is refreshing. If you're going to use AJAX for your delete link then have a look at [this post](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/04/06/mvc-deletelink-with-ajaxhelper.aspx) for all example code. On complete, it does a javascript window.location.reload(); in order to refresh the page.  This follows the [PRG pattern.](http://devlicio.us/blogs/tim_barcz/archive/2008/08/22/prg-pattern-in-the-asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx)

Another approach is the use to not use AJAX. Here is [an example](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/01/08/implementing-a-delete-link-with-mvc-2-and-httpmethodoverride.aspx) for that.

Overall, you're fine sticking with your AJAX approach.

Comment: Good explanation of the problem and a link to a complete solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The another way is to remove that control/html element through javascript. You can call this script when your Ajax request gets completed.

```
<%: Ajax.ActionLink(
                "Delete"
                ,"Delete"
                , new { id=item.FooId}
                , new AjaxOptions()
                { 
                    OnSuccess="deleteElement"   
                    ,Confirm="Are you sure that you want to delete this item?"
                    , HttpMethod = "post"} ) %>
```

`OnSuccess` Option tells the Ajax helper to call the method when ajax requests gets completed successfully.